# Allocate two separate GPU's to different threads in python?

Tags: python, gpu, multi-gpu

I want to use two python source codes, the first one is developed with `tensorflow` and the other is developed using `pythorch`.  I want to run each of these codes in a thread with a separate GPU.  the input of both codes are the same and there are some post-processes when the result of two are ready.

I cannot use tf.device because it gets all available GPU when initializing and I have to use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable.GPU access is selectable via setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in python.

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "Accessible_GPUs"
```

But unfortunately, it seems CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES is not working with threads:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "2"
Thread(target = method_from_code1).start()
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "3"
Thread(target = method_from_code2).start()
```

now the problem is to set different values an environment variable for each thread.  Is there any solution to this issue?